# Finding velocity (Python, idle)

Tags: python

Using the formula `KE=1/2*m*(v**2)`, how can I find the velocity when KE is given.

For example, the mass is `10` and the KE is `50000.0`.
I tried this way:

```
import math

print("Determining the speed to match the Kinetic Energy of the bowling ball dropped in the desert:")
mass = eval(input("Enter the mass of the bowling ball:"))
KE = eval(input("The Kinetic Energy of the ball with a mass of 10 at 100 MPH is:"))
v=0
print("Mass", " ", "Velocity to reach",KE )
for y in range(140, 321, 15):
    v = math.sqrt(2*KE*(1//mass))
    mass+=15
    print (y," ", v)
```

But keep getting the result of:

```
Mass   Velocity to reach 50000.0
140   0.0
155   0.0
```

Where should I fix in order to get the result of:

```
Mass     Velocity to reach 50000.0
140      26.72612419124244
155      25.4000254000381
```

Comment: try 10.0 for mass . This looks like an integer division problem to me. In integer divison, 1 divided by any integer greater than 1 will give 0.

Comment: @Pac0 Still gives me 0

Comment: I just noticed you use eval with your input result... I am not sure that is what you want to do.

Comment: Do you mean to be using `//` for division? That is the floor division operator.

Comment: You should use something like `float(input(...))` instead of `eval(input(...))` if my Python is not too rusted

Comment: Good catch @pstatix, the "//" will force the result to zero if the mass is greater than 1...

Comment: @Pac0 You are correct as well, should drop `eval()` for `float()` cast.

Comment: Further, you are iterating in a range, and assigning the index to `y`. But you never use `y` again in the loop. So if you start with `140` and get result of `100`, then at `155` the result will still be `100` since `y` didn't do anything. Long story short: _What is the point of your loop?_

Comment: Did I do something wrong in my formula? I am getting a wrong number. For example, when mass =140, velocity = 31.622....Which the velocity should be 26.7261...

Comment: @pstatix You're right, I edited my coding

Comment: @HeeRaChoi I've posted my solution, let me know what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should be doing:

```
mass = float(input("Enter the mass of the bowling ball:"))
KE = float(input("The Kinetic Energy of the ball with a mass of 10 at 100 MPH is:"))
v=0
print("Mass", " ", "Velocity to reach",KE )
for y in range(140, 321, 15):
    v = math.sqrt((2*KE)/mass)) # no need for * (1/mass), just divide
    mass+=15
    print (y," ", v)
```

Of note, you are calling the increment operator `+=` on `mass`. So once you've iterated, `mass` will no longer be `10`. So running the loop again produces different results.

**Edit**

From the comments, it sounds like you want your `mass` to start at `140`. If so, there is no reason to ask the user for a `mass` as `input()`. Simply do the following:

```
KE = float(input("The Kinetic Energy of the ball with a mass of 10 at 100 MPH is:"))
v=0
print("Mass", " ", "Velocity to reach",KE )
for mass in range(140, 321, 15):
    v = math.sqrt((2*KE)/mass)) # no need for * (1/mass), just divide
    mass += 15
    print (mass," ", v)
```

Note that if you want the user to supply an `input()` for the `mass` variable, you need to change your loop accordingly.

Comment: I still get the wrong result...when mass =140, velocity = 31.622....Which the velocity should be 26.7261...

Comment: No, it shouldn't. At least not by your program. If you ask the user to supply the `mass` as an `input()`, that is the variable that will be used in the equation for `v`. If you need `mass` to start at `140`, why are you asking the user to supply the `mass` variable?

Comment: @HeeRaChoi I don't understand, is your y supposed to be the mass ? This is apparently the case in your example output,

Comment: @HeeRaChoi See my edit for what you are looking for.

Comment: @Pac0 Yea I think that's what the OP is saying...which is not what the program is doing at all. Hence my question earlier about the loop and why it even exists!